# Google Advertising ID(GAID) by Google and IDFA by Apple can be collided?

Tags: android, ios, idfa, google-advertising-id

Android and iOS developer! (Hopefully Googler or Appler?)

I want to track mobiles for ad by advertising id,
but I encountered one important question.

`Can GAID and IDFA be the same between different two devices in real world?`

Apple and Google seems to be not publishing the algorithm to generate the id,
but we developer tacitly thinking the hex-32 digit numbers are generated randomly,
so no collision would occur.

I want to be sure that no collision happens!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, no collision in the real world. This may be the best answer?

Watch the line line quoted.

```
Google Advertising ID (AAID) for Android devices
 Inventory bid requests from Android devices pass the AAID,
 which provides the same type of device-specific, unique,
 resettable ID for advertising as the IDFA.
 The ID for tablet devices with multiple users may also be unique per user.

 All of the features, encryption and technical details for IDFA also apply to the advertising ID.
```

Sited from https://support.google.com/adxbuyer/answer/3221407?hl=en

Comment: Hi, curious about the same question. Did you figure this out (in a definitive way) in the end? Thanks!

Comment: Both ids are 32 hex numbers (Rumor says GAID is lowercase and IDFA is uppercase). By thinking simple case, the probability of collision of newly created id is 1/16^32. It's said there would be no chance to collide with.